# Density of series the functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

> Let $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq {\cal C}^0([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ with $\sum\int_a^b|g_n(t)|dt < \infty$
>
> 1. Prove that $\sum|g_n(t)|$ converges
> 2. Show that $\{t\in[a,b]~/~\sum|g_n(t)|<\infty\}$ is dense in $[a,b]$

I was looking the notes of a friend and I look this exercise, I try to prove it, but I can't conclude anything.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand. You 1. and 2. are in apparent contradiction. If you remove 1. then this would make sense...

Comment: Why?, if $\sum|g_n(t)|$ depends the "t".
Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, of course $\sum|g_n(t)|$ depends on $t$!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of functions $h_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}|g_{n}(t)|$ is a non-decreasing sequence. Let $h(t)=\lim_{k}h_{k}(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}|g_{n}(t)|$ be an extended real-valued function which can take on values in $(-\infty,+\infty]$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
   \int_{a}^{b}h(t)\,dt = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}h_{k}(t)\,dt=
\lim_{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\int_{a}^{b}|g_{n}(t)|\,gd = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b}|g_{n}(t)|\,gt.
$$
By assumption, the sum on the right is finite. Therefore, $h < \infty$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. In other words, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|g_{n}(t)| < \infty$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. If $E$ is the set on on which this sum is finite, then $E$ is dense in $[a,b]$ because the Lebesgue measure of $[a,b]\setminus E$ is 0 and, thus, $[a,b]\setminus E$ can contain no interval $(r,s)$ where $a \le r < s \le b$.